# Force Mac to backup photos to iCloud

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

I have recently enabled my Mac to backup photos from Photos.app to iCloud.

When I go to iCloud > Manage > Photos it says that there is 25MB of data in iCloud, however when I go to `~/Pictures` and I right click on Photos Library and select Get Info it says that there is 1.1GB of data. I know this is true when I put them into another folder.

How do I force my Mac to upload my photos to iCloud?

This is not a duplicate of [iCloud Photo Library - force upload](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182250/icloud-photo-library-force-upload) since I have less then 250 photos so I am not exceeding the maximum limit.

Comment: The limits you reference in the other post are in regards to uploading to _shared_ iCloud photo albums, not your personal iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: @tubedogg Thanks for clearing that up. Do you suggest to delete that comment I made then?

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181979/photos-stopped-uploading-to-icloud-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 2):

I know this seems a bit stupid. I think it was because I was a bit impatient. My upload speed is 0.71Mb/s (that means it will take 3 hours 43 minutes to upload!). It has only uploaded 170MB/1.1GB. I have however had my computer asleep for a few hours though.

Even though I have posted this I would still like to know how to force upload incase I need to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on OS X 10.10 (with Photos.app): make sure you've enabled the appropriate checkboxes under "Options..." on the Photos row.

[image: Screenshot of iCloud preference pane, with Photos option opened]

Comment: I had (except photo sharing). That wasn't the issue though. Have a look at my issue.